# How do I find Lapis Lazuli?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't find Lapis Lazuli. I've looked it up on YouTube, but I can't find a good video. Any help?

Comment: Keep mining and you will find it just like anything else.

Comment: Diggy diggy hole. If you spent less time looking things up on YouTube and more time mining you'd probably have found it by now.

Comment: @fredley that's not really true necessarily.  If he has an old enough save game, just digging around won't help unless he goes to a new area (and generates new chunks).   This is because old versions didn't have lapis lazuli.  I've been bitten by this type of issue myself, it's one of the really annoying aspects of minecraft, since in a way it encourages you to NOT explore, otherwise you have to walk forever to find a new chunk when an update comes out (or give up your map and start over).

Comment: @TM. - Or build a Nether railroad.

Comment: @Shinrai that's still a huge hassle... and you have to make new destinations once per update that adds chunk-generation-related features.

Comment: Make a quarry!!

Comment: Down near the bottom few layers. What will happen is that it will catch your eye and you'll think "Diamond!" followed shortly after by "Shit ... lapis ...."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lapis_Lazuli_%28Ore%29):

> Lapis Lazuli ... is
> usually found at a depth of 32 and below, similar to Gold. The highest
> concentration of Lapis Lazuli Ore is found between levels 17 and 19. At this level the concentration is about 0.075%.
>
> Maps generated before lapis lazuli was added will have none of this
> ore unless new terrain is generated.

So go to an area you haven't explored before, and mine down to ~18 blocks above bedrock. That's where you'll find the highest concentration of lapis lazuli (about 0.075%).

Comment: Bedrock goes to Y=5, so mining 18 blocks above the bedrock means mining at Y=23. When you consider a 3 blocks high stripmine this means you'll mine Y=24-26, since you are then standing on the Y=23 block. Instead go to Y= 16 (so 11 blocks above bedrock) and make a 3 high stripmine, then you'll mine the 17-19 blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find caves, or find bedrock then go 11 blocks up, then mine around that layer of rock. There might be huge cave systems and ravines. I find tons of Lapis in these systems; I have enough to make tons of Lapis Lazuli blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Strip mine.  I have found over 2 stacks in one mc PE world but none in my other mc PE world

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Good farm setup of pumpkin, melon and carrots. then you can trade it with villager to get emerald. Which can be traded for lapis lazuli. This is what I do most of time. I mean who needs to go for mining when you can simply trade them.

Answer (score -2):

If you cannot find more than 10 lapis lazuli you have the double amount of them if you know the glitch the glitch is press LT and the menu button at the same time on Xbox until a chest stays open throw your blocks to it and lapis you are throwing will not leave your little inventory then turn the lapis you have into lapis lazuli blocks the collect lapis you throwed then turn the lapis that you turned into lapis lazuli blocks to lapis lazuli then you will have the double amount lapis you mined

Answer (score -4):

I think it is a hard ore to find but when you do you get like 6 so it is easy to make lapis lazuli blocks and duplicate it if you have minecraft pe but if you don't know how look it up on youtube

Comment: Could you enclose a link to such a youtube video or some other guide? Because without it there's no real answer here. Also, if what you offer is exploiting a glitch in the game, it would be better to say that explicitly.

Comment: This question isn't about Pocket Edition